# ActiveMQ debugging lost messages

Tags: java, debugging, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to use ActiveMQ in my application. In order to test it, I wrote two small Java applications, one acting as a Message Broker (server) and one application acting as a client. The client is able to publish messages to the server and they are supposed to be sent back to all clients (similar to a chat room chat client). It works all well between a few machines even across a VPN network, but a few clients act up funny. Especially one computer connects properly to the client and message sent from it will be sent to all clients, but it just does not receive message sent from other clients.

I am now wondering on how could I possibly debug this behaviour. I disabled the firewall on that machine, but I am still not able to resolve the issue.

Is there anything I can do to debug this in a convenient way?

Cheers,
Max

Comment: can you post your code/configuration?

Comment: Do you see the messages sent from your "funny" client in amq web console? Where do you send them to? Topic, Virtual Topic, Queue?